# Is it possible to fetch the results of a custom report via API?

Tags: docusignapi

I created a custom report that's saved in Docusign. It runs year-to-date and it only captures data for envelopes with a "completed" status.

Right now, I have this report going out to me on a daily basis as an email with a CSV attachment. Would it be possible to query this data using a REST API instead? Ideally, I'd like to use a URL to request these results and return them in a JSON or CSV format.

I looked for some information about this in the help documentation, but I did not come across anything relevant. If someone can point me in the right direction, that'd be great.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No, the results of the built-in Reporting tool can't be accessed via the API.

DocuSign is developing an advanced reporting API called Data Feed. If you'd be interested in learning more about that, reach out to your Account Manager.